# Formatting differences between sprintf() and wsprintf() in VS2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am moving some code from multibyte to unicode, and finding my string formatting coming out wrong. It looks like Visual Studio 2015 handles the width argument specifier '*' differently between sprintf() and wsprintf(). Is this a compiler bug or side-effect, or am I missing something really obvious?

Code below, with output:

```
char    cOutA [ 64 ];
wchar_t wcOutA [ 64 ];

sprintf ( cOutA, "Multibyte = %.*f\n", 3, 2.12345 );
wsprintf ( wcOutA, L"Unicode = %.*f\n", 3, 2.12345 );

printf ( cOutA );
wprintf ( wcOutA );
```

---

Output:

```
Multibyte = 2.123
Unicode = *f
```

---

I was expecting both to give me a floating point number to 3 decimal places. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wsprintf was a helper function built into Windows.  Goes back to Win3 and having to cram an OS and its apps in 640KB of memory.  It does cut one corner, it has no support for floating point.  The MSDN article yells "do not use".  Use the CRT function instead, swprintf.

Comment: You are right Hans, but the MSDN documentation and compiler tells me off about all of the string functions in the C standard library and I am compiling old code. However it seems wsprintf() is broken for floats but swprintf() is not. This seems rather confusing as it is easy to mix them up, especially since the other TCHAR functions tend to have "t" in the name, e.g. _tcscpy()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by Hans in the comments, the answer is you should never use wsprintf(). It's always been broken, does not support the same formatting arguments as C standard "swprintf()" and the Microsoft documentation does not make clear how it is broken or why.

I only discovered this when trying to debug a related function: wvsprintf(). This function seems to have the same limitations, and should also be replaced by its working replacement: "vswprintf()". The similarity of the names to the working versions is very unfortunate, as is the apparent closeness to standard C library functions and naming methodologies. I have no idea why these functions are still delivered in 2017, nor why the Microsoft compiler does not generate a warning when used with unsupported arguments in the same way it does for "sprintf()".

I'm posting this for visibility as searching for these functions on Google doesn't seem to make these massive flaws obvious.