# sprintf vs. wsprintf in VS2017 with "%.*s"

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2017

While trying to output some counted strings, I encountered the following asymmetry between the Microsoft's `sprintf()` and `wsprintf(`) functions:

```
#define _UNICODE

sprintf(buff, "%.3s", "abcdef");  //Outputs: "abc"
sprintf(buff, "%.*s", 3, "abcdef");  //Outputs: "abc"

wsprintf(buff, L"%.3s", L"abcdef");  //Outputs: L"abc"
wsprintf(buff, L"%.*s", 3, L"abcdef");  //Outputs: L"*s"
```

Note that the last `wsprintf()` does not output `L"abc"` like its narrow sister function `sprintf()` with the same (but wide) arguments.

**Q**: Is this a bug or feature?

**Note**: *This is similar to the issue described here:
[Formatting differences between sprintf() and wsprintf() in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824633/formatting-differences-between-sprintf-and-wsprintf-in-vs2015)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wsprintf` is old, very old. It does not document `*` in precision, so don't pass that format string to `wsprintf`. Your test is technically unspecified.

Please note that `wsprintf` will not write more than 1023 characters to `buff` followed by the null character, and in UCS-2 rather than UTF-16. The design of this function is you pass it a fixed size stack buffer of 1024 and don't worry about buffer overflow since it truncates for you.

As far as I can tell for its intention it's more intended for making debug messages to pass to `MessageBox` rather than for actual application use. It's a much-reduced form of `snprintf` with a fixed `n` that's implemented independently of the other standard libraries.

Ok so you want a `swprintf` that always null terminates. Try this:

```
int swprintf2(wchar_t *ws, size_t len, const wchar_t* format, ...)
{
    va_arg arg;
    va_start(arg, format);
    ws[len - 1] = 0;
    return vswprintf(ws, len - 1, format, arg);
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson: I think like so should do what you want.

Comment: OK, so `wsprintf()` sucks and should not be used...but what to use instead of it?  The `swprintf()` function seems to processes the format string `“%.*s”` correctly.